# django geocoder to find near by coordinates

Tags: django, google-geocoder

I'm using geocoder, I have database of coordinates, I want to fetch the coodinates within the radius of 5 km using geocoder. In rails I could do that as followed:

```
 Venue.near([40.71, -100.23], 20)    # venues within 20 miles of a point
```

how to do this using django geocoder????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [How to get the nearest location entries from a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765052/how-to-get-the-nearest-location-entries-from-a-database).
Example :

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
from myapp.models import MyResult

pnt = fromstr('POINT(48.796777 2.371140 )', srid=4326)
qs = MyResul

t.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=20)))
```

Comment: I'm not using postgis, I have stored lat, long in separate columns